# Add one row from table to table

Tags: java, sql, spring, thymeleaf

I'm making pet app(shop) and i'm confused about one thing - i don't understand how to add product to shopping cart. I have 2 tables -  products and cart, they have same fields. Here is my code with Thymeleaf:

```
<tbody>
            <tr th:each="products : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${products.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${products.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${products.quantity}"></td>
                <td th:text="${products.serial}"></td>
                <td>    <p><a href="/product-add" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a></p>
                </td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here is my controller, what is supposed to save one row from products to cart:

```
 @RequestMapping("product-add")
    public String addToCart (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("selection", cartRepository.selection());
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
```

and query(i know that it copies all products to cart, but its only for example):

```
 @Query(value = "insert into cart(select * from products )", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Cart> selection();
```

My question is - how can i copy just one row(one product) in this case? How i can separate product id for adding to cart? should it be done in controller or maybe in sql query?I'm just missing something simple((

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your query is selecting all columns from products with the `*` sign. What you can do is try limiting the query result by using `limit 1` after products.

Also if you want to extract rows with certain product id, you can try simple `where` keyword that specify conditions. e.g. `where product_id = your_desired_id` it should return all rows that match your requirement id.

If you want to actually separate the entire product_id column from your result to cart. Why not try `select [input_here_columns_besides_product_id] from products`?

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for a answer. Let me explain - i have iteration over table 'product'(first part of code), and there i have button to add product to cart near every product. Question lies in 'how to add THIS product to a cart'. So, i have 5 products and 5 buttons for adding first product, second etc, something like that=) If i specify in query "insert into cart(select * from products where id like "1"", i just set all my buttons to add  product with id 1 to be added on submit.

Comment: I see, do you have any connection between products and buttons? You have to have some sort of identifier to bundle the button and product together, right? What you need is to use that identifier, in what every form e.g. product_id, to select from query to another table

Comment: so, here lies my question - i just don't undestand how to implement this thing